# Getting the value of list of inputs in react

Tags: reactjs, list, input, getvalue

I have list of input tags in my react app. I want to get the value of all inputs when I click on submit button.

I can get the value of one input, but not able to get all the values in one go.

```
keys.map(i => <Input fullWidth defaultValue={i} />)


<Button>Submit</Button>
```

get the list of values

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: @Anjali you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58619381/6544460... i hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sample application for multiple inputs

```
const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([
    { firstName: "Herry", lastName: "Sejal" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Siri" },
    { firstName: "Bukky", lastName: "Sera" }
  ]);
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  const onChange = e => {
    setPerson({ ...person, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newVal = [...people, person];
    setPeople(newVal);
    setPerson({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <h2>Add a person: </h2>
          <hr />
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="firstName"
                placeholder="First Name.."
                value={person.firstName}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="lastName"
                placeholder="Last Name.."
                value={person.lastName}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
              Add person
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <h2>People: </h2>
          <hr />
          {people.map(p => (
            <div key={Math.random() * 1000000000}>
              <p>
                {p.firstName} {p.lastName}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```